# Where should I add custom redirects in Joomla?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla, redirect

Where do I add redirects?

**Based on this page:**
http://dvlancer.com/67-redirect-pages-with-html-suffix.html

When turning turning html suffix off I should use this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Just putting above .htaccess (in public_html folder) did not effect anything:

Should this be put in htaccess.txt instead ? It seems to be a section where custom things should be included?

```
## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
## End - Custom redirects
```

Comment: Is `mod_rewrite` on?

Comment: @hjpotter92 It's turned off in htaccess, but turned on in .htaccess.txt

Answer (score 1):

`mod_rewrite` is not something that can be turned off location-wise. You enable/load the rewrite module from the apache's server settings. It is usually stored in `/etc/apache2/conf.d/` with the file name either `httpd.conf` or `apache2.conf`.

Search for the following text in the file:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

and if it is commented (preceeded with `#`); uncomment it, restart the server.

---

The rewrite rules need to be put in a file named **`.htaccess`**. The file `htaccess.txt` is there for help to new developers and does not get processed by the server. Also, you need to have `RewriteEngine On` statement before evaluating any other rewrite features.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Ok then this is very weird. I changed some content in the htaccess.txt and after that the server did not work... thats why I asked this question. But thanks a lot! I tried to restore files .htaccess and .htaccess.txt but server still does not work ): I don't have any access to the apache-configuration or such, but I don't undestand what went wrong...